# Link java class to xml file in android

Tags: java, xml, hyperlink

I would like to link java class to my xml file.
There is no error in the coding however, it gave me force close.
I would like to know what's wrong with it.
Can anyone please advice me?

I've one main java class, having the same code as this, as I would like to display the same thing for both xml layout.
The main java class work perfectly fine, however, when I try to convert the coding to second java class, the force close error occurs.

Here is my coding.

```
public class event extends ListActivity{

    ArrayList<String> psi;

      public TextView psi_text;

    TextView weather;
     ImageView image;
     private static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     class MyWeather{


      String conditiontext;
      String conditiontemp;
      String conditiondate;



      public String forecastToString(){

       return 
         conditiontext + "\n" + "        "  + conditiontemp + "°C"  ;

      } 

     }
      String[] Category = {
                "Scientist for a day",
                "Science Trail",
                "Megalog Return"



        };

        String [] dates = {
                "Today",
                "Tomorrow",
                "This Week"

        };

        Spinner s1;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.event);
            weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);
            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            psi = new ArrayList<String>();              
            psi_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.psi_text);


            TabHost th =(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
            th.setup();
            TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
            specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
            specs.setIndicator("Suggested");
            th.addTab(specs);
            specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
            specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
            specs.setIndicator("All");
            th.addTab(specs);

            TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) th.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
            View tab1 = tw.getChildTabViewAt(0);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tab1.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 50);

            View tab2 = tw.getChildTabViewAt(1);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) tab2.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv1.setTextSize(15);
            tv1.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 50);



        //GridView
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Category)); 

            //SpinnerView
            s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dates);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have seleted item :" + dates[index] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {}
            });



            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;                 

                    NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("psi");
                    Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                    websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                    psi.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());           

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
            }



            String temp = Html.fromHtml(psi.get(0)).toString(); 
            String a[] = temp.split("\\)");
            psi_text.setText(""+a[0]+")");


            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                 @Override
                   public void run() {
                    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
                          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

                          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                              @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                  weather.setText(weatherResult.forecastToString());
                                 }});

                               }});
                                    myThread.start();
                                }

     private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

         MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

            //<yweather:condition.../>
         Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);


         String weatherCode = conditionNode.getAttributes()
               .getNamedItem("code")
               .getNodeValue()
               .toString();

         // thunderstorms
         if(weatherCode.equals("4")){

             mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify
                    // Views

                     image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                }
            });
         }

         //isolated thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("37")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }


         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("38")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //scattered thunderstorms
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("39")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("45")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //isolated thundershowers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("47")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.thunderstorm);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //drizzle
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("9")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

         //showers
         else if ( weatherCode.equals("11")) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
                        }
                    });
                }

//showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("12")) {
  mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

          image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
      }
  });
}

         //scattered showers
else if ( weatherCode.equals("40")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
            }
        });
    }

         //hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("17")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }


         //mixed rain and hail
else if ( weatherCode.equals("35")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hail);
            }
        });
    }

         //foggy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("20")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //haze
else if ( weatherCode.equals("21")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //smoky
else if ( weatherCode.equals("22")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.foggy);
            }
        });
    }

         //windy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("24")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.windy);
            }
        });
    }

         //cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("26")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("33")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //fair (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("34")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy
else if ( weatherCode.equals("44")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("27")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //partly cloudy (night)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("29")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.night_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }

         //mostly cloudy (day)
else if ( weatherCode.equals("28")) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
            }
        });
    }


         //partly cloudy (day)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("30")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.day_cloudy);
                }
            });
        }




         //clear(night)
    else if ( weatherCode.equals("31")) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.moon);
                }
            });
        }


         //sunny
    else {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunny);
                }
            });
        }




         myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
     .getNamedItem("text")
     .getNodeValue()
     .toString();

         myWeather.conditiontemp = conditionNode.getAttributes()
                   .getNamedItem("temp")
                   .getNodeValue()
                   .toString();




   return myWeather; 
  }

  private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){

   Document dest = null;
   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder parser;

   try {
    parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes())); 
   } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(event.this,
      e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   } catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(event.this,
      e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(event.this,
      e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }

   return dest; 
  }

  private String QueryYahooWeather(){

   String qResult = "";
   String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c";

   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

   try {
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

    if (httpEntity != null){
     InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
     Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
     BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

     String stringReadLine = null;

     while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
     }

     qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
    } 
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(event.this,
      e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(event.this,
      e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   }

   return qResult; 
  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id)
  {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + Category[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the

```
setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_NAME);
```

in your activity. That's why you could not connect your java class and xml file